# EF Code first, unidirectional many to many relationship not by Id of second entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, data-modeling

This is my first time asking something in Stack, and I've already searched a lot w/o any luck.

I'm using EF 4 and I want to create a many to many relationship using code first.
The problem I have is that the application is localized and has currently two languages (Spanish and English)
Because of that I've created two entities:
Practitioner and Speciality:

```
[Table("Practitioners")]
public class PractitionerModel
{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public ICollection<SpecialityModel> Specialities { get; set; }
}

[Table("Specialities")]
public class SpecialityModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

I want a Practitioner to have many Specialities and want the "Mapping" to happen by Code not by Id
Since there are two Specialities with the same code for example: Ginecology and Ginecologia"
They are the same speciality and have code 12 with different Ids.

The idea is that the data in the db should look like:

```
-----------------                                        ------------------------------------------
| Practitioner |                                         |     Specialities                       |
----------------      ------------------------------     ------------------------------------------    
| Id = 10      |--   | PractitionerToSpecialities |   -- | Id = 1, Code = 12, Name = "Ginecology" | 
----------------  |  ------------------------------  |   ------------------------------------------
                   --| PracId = 10, SpecCode = 12 |----- | Id = 2, Code = 12, Name = "Ginecologia"|
                      -----------------------------      ----------------------------------------    --
```

Is there any way to acchieve this with CodeFirst?

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to keep you data model "neutral" (ie having only one speciality called "Ginecology") and to localize your application using resource files ?

Comment: Thx for your answer, the thing is that it is going to have many clients, and some of them won't be .NET to have them localized. Also if a new language is added it is going to be just a matter of adding more rows to the table with the same codes but different Name.

Answer (score 0):

Globalization should not affect your database design in this way.

It would be much better to simply have one specialty record per specialty (thus the relationship could be by id), and then corresponding resources (either in the .NET resource manager or as fields in the specialty table) for displaying the name in different languages.

That said, try something like this:

```
[Table("Practitioners")]
public class PractitionerModel
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Specialties")]
    public virtual int Code {get; set; }
    public ICollection<SpecialityModel> Specialities { get; set; }
}

[Table("Specialities")]
public class SpecialityModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It could be done that way. It's just that it will complicate the datamodel a little bit. If there is no possibility to do what I wanted to achieve, that I'll go that path

Comment: @user2968933 I'd say going your original route will complicate the data model more than this would.